# Biopython(SeqIO) 'FileNotFoundError'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bioinformatics, biopython, file-not-found

I am new to BioPython and am trying to use several modules.
However, as you can see, in the process of using files such as Genbank or FASTA, such an error appears in the next module.
Can I ask how to solve it, and what procedure should I go through?

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCBz8.png)

The Genbank file was also saved in the computer, but the file is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure, that your file is in the same directory as your notebook file. If you don't want to move the file near your notebook file, then you have to give a full path to your GenBank file, for example:

#### Bad

```
from Bio import SeqIO

record = SeqIO.parse("file.gb", "genbank")
```

#### Good

```
from Bio import SeqIO 
record = SeqIO.parse(r"path/to/your/file", "genbank")
```